# Creating custom tasks in NopCommerce

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, scheduled-tasks, nopcommerce

I'm wondering if anyone has experience making custom tasks in NopCommerce.

I need to create a task that a toplist of the most sold products per day. I know NopCommerce has the "bestsellers"  in which best selling products are displayed on the homepage. Maybe I can refer the task to the bestseller class/controller?

Does anybody know how this works?

Thx

/Chris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Talking about BestSeller logic in `NopCommerce` there is method in `OrderReportService` which is called as below in `HomepageBestSellers` action of `Catalog` controller

```
_orderReportService.BestSellersReport(.........
```

TO CREATE CUSTOM TASK:->

You just need to create one more Entry in `ScheduleTask` table.

E.g

```
ID: 10
Name: Task Name
Seconds:100
Type:Nop.Services.Messages.BestSellers, Nop.Services
Enabled:1
StopOnError:0
```

Now in your project at path `Nop.Services\Messages` you need to create class with same name as specified in database which in above case is '`BestSellers`'. Now In your created class write Method like below

```
  public partial class BestSellers : ITask
        {
          public void Main()
           {
           //Your implementation to perform task goes here 
           }
        }
```

Now this method will be called after every 100 seconds as I have specified 100 in seconds' field in database

Hope It Helps!

**Note: You can create this class anywhere in Nop.Service . but that path should match with path specified with database.**

Comment: I know this is an old question,Today I create a Task somewhere out of `Nop.Service`. And it works like a charm. My task class is in `Nop.Plugin.Shop.SpecialCart.SendLogTask.cs`
I just set  `Type`:`Nop.Plugin.Shop.SpecialCart.SendLogTask,Nop.Services`And it works fine.